# When I set an object using an Action<> the object assigned is always null

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, desktop-application

My goal is create an Action<> for set the configuration object in the constructor.

The Action<> that I have defined, set two configuration objects by reference, but the problem is that the assigned object is always null. I thought that internally, the objects, were assigned by reference but it seems that no.

In the example code, I have created a CarConfiguration in the main program and I try to set by reference this configuration to my new Car using an Action<> which defines the assignment between the main program CarConfiguration and the Car attribute configuration.

Why my car configuration attribute is always null even though is being assigned by reference in my Action<> method?

Main Class:

```
CarConfiguration carConfiguration = new CarConfiguration()
{
    CarName = "Ferrari",
    CarModel = "LaFerrari",
    Spolier = true,
    BuildDate = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01)
};

//Thats not work because the "conf" parameter is never assign in the Car constructor
Car myOwnCar = new Car(conf => 
{
    conf = carConfiguration;
});
Console.WriteLine(myOwnCar.CarConfigurationText());

//That works, but is not my purpose do it like this!
Car myOtherCar = new Car(carConfiguration);
Console.WriteLine(myOtherCar.CarConfigurationText());
```

Configuration Class:

```
public class CarConfiguration
{
    public bool Spolier { get; set; } = false;
    public string CarName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string CarModel { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public DateTime BuildDate { get; set; } = default(DateTime);
}
```

Car Class:

```
public class Car
{
    private CarConfiguration carConfiguration = null;

    //That does not work because carConfiguration is not assigned in the Action as a reference
    public Car(Action<CarConfiguration> configureCar)
    {
        configureCar(carConfiguration);
    }

    //That works!
    public Car(CarConfiguration configureCar)
    {
        carConfiguration = configureCar;
    }

    public string CarConfigurationText()
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        if (carConfiguration != null)
        {
            strBuilder.AppendLine(carConfiguration.CarModel);
            strBuilder.AppendLine(carConfiguration.CarName);
            strBuilder.AppendLine(carConfiguration.Spolier.ToString());
            strBuilder.AppendLine(carConfiguration.BuildDate.ToString("mm-DD-yyyy"));
        }
        else
        {
            strBuilder.AppendLine("Car is not configure!");
        }

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image: Link output example]

Comment: Why do you need an `Action<T>` as a parameter for the constructor?  A `Func<T>` would actually return a value, however this design seems off.

Comment: Your lambda expression `conf => { conf = carConfiguration; }` is equivalent to a method `void Method(CarConfiguration conf) { conf = carConfiguration; }` Do you see it? (Also, read the documentation for the Action<T> delegate carefully and attentively)

Comment: This pattern is whack, if you want to use a configuration action you have to configure that object inside the action. If you already have a config object, you should just pass the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action is assigning the configuration to the lambda parameter which has no effect as the parameter is an input value, it does not get returned out of the lambda. Objects are passed by reference, but references are copied to parameters in function calls, i.e. `conf` will receive a copy of the reference to `carConfiguration` when you call the action like so `configureCar(carConfiguration);`

Assigning and overwriting this local copy of the reference serves no purpose. You have to use the `ref` keyword to essentially pass a reference to the reference(variable) to the object. When assigning to a variable marked with `ref` it will overwrite the reference held in the original member variable and not the local variable inside the lambda. This is already demonstrated in the other answer.

The proper method to implement what you are trying to accomplish is not by passing references around but by configuring the object inside the action. If you want to use an existing configuration just pass the object as you've already done so. There is  no need to write an action that accepts a reference to an object in an explicit manner.

```
public Car(Action<CarConfiguration> configureCar)
{
  carConfiguration = new CarConfiguration();
  configureCar(carConfiguration);
}

// This is the common configuration pattern seen in .NET
Car myOwnCar = new Car(conf => 
{
    conf.CarName = "Ferrari";
    conf.CarModel = "LaFerrari"
    /** etc **/
});
```

If you want to copy values from an existing configuration, you can write a method to do so

```
public static class CarConfigurationExtensions
{
  public static void CopyTo(CarConfiguration this source, CarConfiguration dest){
    dest.CarName = source.CarName;
    dest.CarModel = source.CarModel;
    // etc
  }
}


Car myOwnCar = new Car(conf => carConfiguration.CopyTo(conf));
```

But under no circumstance is writing an action that accepts a `ref` to a local variable a thing. Another alternative is to use a `Func<CarConfiguration>` like so, maybe if you want to do a lazy intialization.

```
public Car(Func<CarConfiguration> configurator)
{
  _configurator = configurator;
}

private Func<CarConfiguration> _configurator;
private CarConfiguration _carConfiguration;

public CarConfiguration CarConfiguration => 
  _carConfiguration ?? (_carConfiguration = _configurator());

Car myOwnCar = new Car(() => carConfiguration);
```

Note how the configuration is instantiated and stored- the first time it is accessed, perhaps the only time accepting a function in the constructor is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if instead of `Action<CarConfiguration>` you had used `Action<ref CarConfiguration>` (assuming this was legal), to allow passing the argument by reference. But there is no build-in `Action<ref Τ>`, so if you want one you should make it yourself:

```
public delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T arg1);
```

...and then use `RefAction<CarConfiguration>` instead of `Action<CarConfiguration>`.

Comment: That's a really weird suggestion. It might be workable, but why doing such strange thing if one could easily use a Func<TOut> delegate type?

Comment: @elgonzo personally I wouldn't do that in this case. Passing arguments by reference may be useful in some cases, but I don't think this is one of them!